# Import a text file to Postgres on ubuntu?

Tags: sql, postgresql, import, psql

I have a huge text file that is in format of "name:email".
I also created a table that has name and email columns.

How do I upload the text file into the table?

The textfile is on my ubuntu server, and I have connected to psql by using the commands

```
sudo -u postgres psql
\connect <username>"
```

What do I do next in order to import the text file to my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psql` has a `\COPY` command

> `Copy` allows you to do copy data into and out of tables in your
>   database. It supports several modes including:
>
> - binary
> - tab delimited
> - csv delimited

What you need is:

```
\COPY tablename(name,email) FROM '/path/to/file' DELIMITER ':' CSV
```

If you get an error `ERROR: missing data for column "name"`, that means your file has an empty line at the end, just remove it.

Comment: What if there's a line with name:fwef:df@hotmail.com? there's a ':' in the email.

Comment: @Anh then you first need to convert the text file to a CSV compliant format. `sed -E 's/:(.*)$/:"\1"/' /path/to/file > /path/to/file_converted` will wrap `email` column with quotes so that there will be only two columns.

Comment: Then how do i import that to database when it has quotation? Also i notice that in my txt there's '^M' at the each of each line. For example, name:email^M

Comment: @Anh That's a windows line ending. You can remove those using the dos2unix command, if you have that installed.